# <select> and $_POST

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to edit an admin which has username, password and power. The last one is made like this:

```
<?php $showQuery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE id = {$id}"); 
$show = mysqli_fetch_assoc($showQuery); ?>

<p>Power:&nbsp; <select name = "power">
<option value <?php if ($show['power']=='superadmin') {echo " selected";} ?> = "superadmin">Superadmin</option>
<option value <?php if ($show['power']=='admin') {echo " selected";} ?> = "admin">Admin</option>
<option value <?php if ($show['power']=='moderator') {echo " selected";} ?> = "moderator">Moderator</option>
</select><br /><br />
```

Then I want to catch these values:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['editAdmin'])) {

$username = $_POST['username']; 
if (!$_POST['password'] == "") { $password = $_POST['password']; }
$power = $_POST['power'];

$editQuery = "UPDATE admins SET ";
$editQuery .= "username = '{$username}', ";
if (isset($password)) { $editQuery .= "hashed_pwd = '{$password}', "; }
$editQuery .= "power = '{$power}' ";
$editQuery .= "WHERE id = {$id} LIMIT 1";

$editAdmin = mysqli_query($db, $editQuery);
```

Now, if I don't want to change the power of the admin (leave the option unchanged) and hit Edit, the power becomes blank. If, however, I change the power (upgrade or downgrade) it get set OK. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all your code is invalid. `<option value <?php if ($show['power']=='superadmin') {echo " selected";} ?> = "superadmin">Superadmin</option>` Needs to be `<option value= "superadmin"<?php if ($show['power']=='superadmin') {echo " selected";} ?>>Superadmin</option>` (similar for the other options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly constructing your select, you have the `options` set like this:

```
<option value <?php if ($show['power']=='admin') {echo " selected";} ?> = "admin">Admin</option>
```

where they should be like this:

```
<option value="admin" <?php if ($show['power']=='admin') {echo " selected";} ?> >Admin</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change option outputing to

```
<option value="superadmin" <?php if ($show['power']=='superadmin') {echo "selected";} ?>>Superadmin</option>
```